# MySQL AFTER Update trigger with New.col<> OLD.col

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

The goal here is to update and concatenate a text field from one table to another based on  conditions. When a text col gets updated with some text from a user form, run After update trigger.

The trigger runs but updates all the columns not just the one that has changed.Trying to understand how to just update the correct row only.

Here's what i have so far-
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4278)

```
| ID | SUBID | SWNOTES |
|----|-------|---------|     Table 1
|  1 |    40 |    test |
|  2 |    60 |         |



| ID | SUBID | CONTENT | SWFLAG |
|----|-------|---------|--------|
|  1 |    40 |   hello |      0 |     Table 2
|  2 |    60 | nothing |      0 |


CREATE TRIGGER `updatecontentnotes` AFTER UPDATE ON `tab1`
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

IF New.swnotes <> OLD.swnotes
THEN
    Update `tab2` 
Inner Join `tab1` ON `tab2`.`subid` = `tab1`.`subid` 
Set `tab2`.`swflag` = '1',`tab2`.`content` = CONCAT(`tab2`.`content`, `tab1`.`swnotes`)

Where `tab2`.`subid` = `tab1`.`subid` AND `tab2`.`swflag` = '0';

END IF;

END//
```

And if I update the table with say:

```
  Update `tab1`
set `swnotes` = "new"
where `subid` = '60'
```

I get :

```
| ID | SUBID |    CONTENT | SWFLAG |
|----|-------|------------|--------|
|  1 |    40 |  hellotest |      1 |
|  2 |    60 | nothingnew |      1 |
```

Now I know it is doing what I am telling it to do. I want to update  just the row that is updated. Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the contents of your trigger will run for every row on `tab1`, you need to be more restrictive in your `WHERE` clause so that it will only affect the rows that have been updated. Right now it updates every row on `tab2`

Try adding this to your trigger SQL:

From:

```
Where `tab2`.`subid` = `tab1`.`subid` AND `tab2`.`swflag` = '0';
```

To:

```
Where `tab2`.`subid` = `tab1`.`subid` AND `tab2`.`swflag` = '0' AND `tab2`.`id` = OLD.id;
```

This produces the results that I think you are looking for:

```
| ID | SUBID |    CONTENT | SWFLAG |
|----|-------|------------|--------|
|  1 |    40 |      hello |      0 |
|  2 |    60 | nothingnew |      1 |
```

The updated SQLFiddle is here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fa2d2/1/0